# Rendering a partial view in MVC with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an asp.net MVC website that consists of a topbar and a main area.

Via a js function, I want to be able to retrieve new data from my Controller and display these data in the main area of my website, but without re-rendering the topbar area.

How do I do this?

Here is what I got:

I put the topbar and all related scripts in the `_layout.cshtml`, scripts related to the mainview go to `Display.cshtml` and the data itself which I want to display go inside `Partial_ChartView.cshtml`

The partial view that should display my chart data is loaded inside `Display.cshtml` like this:

```
@model MobileReports.Models.ReportViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{Html.RenderPartial("Partial_ChartView");}
```

The partial view `Partial:ChartView.cshtml` looks like this:

```
@model MobileReports.Models.ReportViewModel
<div id="chartContainer">@Model.Chart</div>
```

The corresponding controller contains this code:

```
public ActionResult Display(Guid? id)
{
    ReportViewModel viewModel = new ReportViewModel();
    Guid validId = (Guid)id;
    viewModel.Chart = GetChart(guid);
    viewModel.ChartData = GetData(guid);
    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

When I open the page at ../Report/Display , the page seems to get rendered correctly.

Now I want to add a script that calls Display(id) with a certain value. Then I want to re-render only the main area (inside div #chartContainer) to display the new data which should now be in the model.
How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using the JQuery library?

Comment: Have a look at [jquery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Yes I am using jquery in diffent parts of the application already. I have read about jquery.load(), but had no success in trying to use it. Could you give an example? The problem with jquey.load was that it always contained the whole site, not just the part I want to display

Comment: `$('#chartContainer').load('@Url.Action("Display", "Report")', { id: YourGUIDValue });`

Comment: you have to use jquery only to load specific area of partial view

Comment: @StephenMuecke :This tries to render the entire page again inside the div. My topbar is displayed twice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kartikeya: How would I do this? Sorry thats the first time I am writing a web application..

Comment: @buddybubble, What does the `Display` render? The whole page or just the chart? You need a new method that just renders the chart (or whatever it is you want to replace in `#chartContainer`)

Comment: Display seems to render the entire page, please see my code above, I have posted the Display(guid) method there. How do I write a controller method that only updates the model and returns it, without rendering the entire page?

Comment: return `PartialView(viewModel)` instead of `View(viewModel)`

Comment: @Carl: I am doing this already

Comment: Create a new method (say `public ActionResult Chart(GUID id) {..`) that returns a `partialview` containing only the data you want to replace.

Comment: @buddybubble - sorry missed that. I think it's because you are re-loading the original view, rather than your partial. you need a second actionresult you call that returns PartialView("Partial_ChartView", viewModel)

Comment: @StephenMuecke & Carl : You both gave the correct answer. I had to create a new method that returns the PartialView. For some strange reason I could just copy the entire Display method, give it a new name and call it as Stephan described in his first post. If either one of you posts his answer, I will accept it as the solution. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new method that returns a partial view containing only the data you need

```
public ActionResult Chart(GUID id)
{
  .....
  return PartialView(someModel);
}
```

then use jquery `.load` to replace the contents of your div

```
$('#chartContainer').load('@Url.Action("Chart", "Report")', { id: YourGUIDValue });
```